# Export AWS Parameter Store environment variables to PHP during build?

Tags: php, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have a simple Laravel installation that I am trying to set up to run through a AWS CodePipeline using ECS.

**What have I done?**

My Codepipeline is set up with a `buildspec.yml` file, where I have specified that it should use a value from the Parameter Store, like

```
env:
    parameter-store:
        TEST_STRING: "TEST"
```

My `TEST` variable does exist in the Parameter Store and I can get it using the cli.

**What do I want to do?**

I want my environment variable to be accessible to my Laravel installation, so I can use the Parameter Store to save passwords and usernames for e.g. databases and apis.

**What actually happens?**

When I try to access the environment variable through php, I'm not getting any value. If I `var_dump` $_ENV, then I cannot see my TEST_STRING in the given array.

I'm quite sure that the environment variable only exists in the build process, but I cannot figure out how to "transfer" the environment variable from my build process to the deployed code.

**Question**

What am I missing to make the environment variables from the build process available to the deployed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your cluster and the find your Task Definitions for the relevant task you want to add some environment variables to.

Click to create a new revision of the task you wish to add variables to.

Under "Container definitions" you have a list of containers on that task. Select the relevant container and a modal will roll from the right of the screen.

Scroll down a bit and find Environment > Environment Variables. Here you can add environment variables. You can either set a static value (by using "value") or a Parameter Store value (by using "valueFrom").

Save your new revision and remember to update your service to use the new definition.